# Login screen password with two languages in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: login, password, 23.04

I use Ubuntu 23.04, and I use both English and Hebrew keyboards.
When logging in I'm getting asked for a password, and sometimes my keyboard is set to the wrong language.
It's not a problem to switch the language.
Still, I've been wondering if there's a more elegant solution, like making the default language for the lock screen English or even making the password "not-language-sensitive" (accept a password that is rightly typed but in the wrong language).
Any ideas or known solutions?

Comment: Well, the language is not the problem, but the alphabet / letters use. I assume the Hebrew keyboard has Hebraic letters while your English keyboard has Latin letters?
A very simply work-around would to use ASCII characters which are present on both keyboards, like numbers, punctuation, brackets and characters lime $%&§ etc.

Comment: @noisefloor My password does include letters, but I want to keep it as it is, and at the same time to be able to type it with the other language.